# forward compatibility in unmarshalling using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have different versions of schema. I am only adding additional attributes in future versions (not deleting or not changing data type). I want to handle a data coming from future version. unmarshalling of older schema works fine but when i try to unmarshall xml from higher version using older xsd then it fails. i want to avoid/neglect that extra attribute. Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: I am setting the schema for unmarshalling. The error am getting if I include "temp" as an extra attribute in xml is : cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'temp'. No child element is expected at this point

Answer (score 0):

The older schema (xsd) file doesn't include the attributes that are specified as allowed in the newer schema file. When the unmarshaller tries to validate a document that includes the new attributes specified by the new schema against the older schema, it fails because the new attributes are unknown to the old schema.

However, the [documentation here](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.7/docs/ch03.html#unmarshalling-unmarshalling-is-not-working-help) (see 4.2.1 in particular) specifies that invalid content is simply skipped over by the unmarshaller, which sounds like what you want. I can't independently verify this, since I haven't tried it. Are you using the current release of JAXB?

Answer (score 0):

### Without Schema Validation

There will be no issues as all extra content will be ignored.

### With Schema Validation

**Preserve Backwards Compatibility**

New elements/attributes must be added so that they are. It required to be present (I.e. `minOccurs="0"`).

**Preserve Forwards Compatibility**

Always validate against the current version of the XML schema.  For this the latest version of the XML schema must always be found at the same location.